# How to use the content of a .jar file as project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, jar

i received a .jar file and want to use the content of the file `as an Eclipse project` NOT

```
in an Eclipse project
```

I have tried to extract the .jar file, but eclipse doesn't reconize it as java project. 
The Jar file contains .class and .java files.

I already tried this way:

```
1-extract the JAR-file
2-create an new project in eclipse
3-right click on that project
4-import
5-file system
```

But i didn't work!

How can i proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: what does your jar contain ? sources or .class (compiled) sources ?

Comment: it contains .class and .java files

Comment: a jar containing java files (.java) isn't an Eclipse project, you just have to unzip the jar , you've to pout sources (all .java files) within src/main folder and maybe a /lib folder for included (jars). create a java project under eclipse then copy sources and libs to your new project

Comment: I will try it and tell you if it worked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want to modify the code, this works if the JAR contains the source-files:

1. extract the JAR-file
2. create an new project in eclipse
3. show the project (+)
4. right click on the "src" folder
5. import
6. file system
7. choose the folder you want to import
8. check it in the left panel

if you just want to use the classes in the JAR-file

1. rigth click on the project
2. build path.
3. libraries and click on Add external JARS.

if you want to modify the code of the JAR but it does not contain the source files, you need to decompile the class-files.

Comment: I already done the first way but it doesn't work, therfore i'm trying to understand what i'm doing wrong!

Comment: does your jar contain the source-files?

Comment: do you mean .class files?

Comment: you need to unzip the jar and im port the folder like i said

Comment: Oh sorry my error i meantz .java files. Yes it congtains .java files

Comment: did you extract/unzip the jar file? this should create a folder. and you need to import that folder like i said

Comment: I already did it. But it did not work, therefore i am asking here for solutions.

Comment: Ok It work! I'm such a fool! Thy a lot
What about the libraries?

Comment: i don't understand the question. you simply add libaries (also jar-files) to the build path as i said in the 2nd option

Comment: It was just a stupid question... My project has dependencies with oder jars. I will do it like you said in the second option.
Thanks a lot . I will mark your answer as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the code, Simply:

1) Right click on your existing src folder (or a new folder you can create if you want)

2) Select "Import"

3) Under "General" select "Archive File"

4) Browse for your jar file. You will then be able to see all of the jar's contents.

5) Click finish and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

you can attach that jar by following steps-

1. Rigth click on project go to properties
2. Then choose java build path.
3. Then libraries and click on Add external JARS.

Comment: Please read my question again. I modified it for more comprehension. I'm not trying to add a jar to a project, the jar has to BE my project, means i want to do a release of the project, which is currently in the .jar file

Comment: oh sorry. r u able to import project or not? eclipse allow you to import or not?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the source code, or just to use that jar as part of another project? If the former, you need the actual source code, as the jar is compiled, if the latter, simply add it to the build path, by right-clicking the project, selecting Build Path --> Add External Archives

Comment: Please read my question again. I modified it for more comprehension. 
I'm not trying to add a jar to a project, the jar has to BE my project, means use i want to do a release to the project, which is currently in the .jar file